# How to setup quasar project to run on virtualhost apache

Tags: apache2, virtualhost, quasar-framework

I want to run my quasar project on domain.local I have setup my configuration file as below
My configuration:

```html
ServerName domain.local
    ServerAlias *.domain.local
    DocumentRoot /project/

    <Directory "/project/">
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
          RewriteEngine On
          RewriteBase /
          RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
          RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
          RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
          RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
      </IfModule>
    </Directory>
```

Comment: Quasar should be completely independent of your hosting. Do you want to use it with the CLI, or UMD? Have a look at the official site to know the difference. Webpack serves by default on port 8080 through a node server.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your question about Apache, but if you are willing to use [Caddy](https://caddyserver.com/docs/quick-starts/static-files), the configuration would simply be

```
http://domain.local {
    root * /project
    file_server
}
```

You would place in `/project` the files in `<your project>/dist/spa`, generated with `quasar build`